# Problema con &lt; y &gt; HTML y Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Buenas mi duda es esta cuando recibo un valor en una variable quiero que aparezca un icono

este seria el HTML

```
<p><b>Compra : </b><span id="view_compra" class="text-success"></span></p>
```

y con una funcion javacript pido los datos para que llene un modal aqui la funcion:

```
if(result.EV_consolidacion == 1){
        $("#view_compra").text('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>');
      }
```

pero al llegar a HTML llega de esta forma:

```
<p><b>Compra : </b><span id="view_compra" class="text-success">&lt;span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</span></p>
```

y solo me llega literal la linea de codigo, entrando a inspector de elementos y cambiando el valor de & lt; por < y  & gt; por > si me funciona.

Que hago para que reciba el < y > y no su valor & lt; y & gt;

Comment: cambia el .text por .append

Comment: si lo que deseas es agregar dentro de ese espan el nuevo "span" con la clase de icono usa "$("#view_compra").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>');"

Comment: Gracias diego, sirve pero se guarda en cache , la solucion que le busque a eso fue colocar otro icono por si no cumple la condicion

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en que estás añadiendo el icono como si fuera texto y no como la etiqueta **span**, en este caso la solución más practica que se me ocurre es añadirle las clases directamente desde el **javascript** de la siguiente manera:

- Capturas el elemento donde quieres que aparezca tu icono:

---

```
const elemento = document.querySelector('#view_compra');
```

- Le añades las clases de glyphicon al elemento con la propiedad `classlist`:

---

```
elemento.classList.add('glyphicon','glyphicon-ok');
```

Espero que te sirva ;)

Comment: Listo Gracias, funciona , pero se queda como el resultado en cache jajaja mi solucion para eso fue colocar un icono tambien para cuando no cumpla la condicion.

Comment: ahora me guarda el resultado anterior no importa si cumpla o no la condicion :c

Comment: @Roga claro y es que esta solución te agrega clases y si quieres cambiar el icono debes eliminar la clase anterior y escribir la nueva (asumo que la que quieres cambiar es glyphicon-ok). Además te presentaron otras soluciones en las que agregas un objeto como html en vez de texto y es que debes diferenciar el agregar texto normal o texto que debe ser interpretado como html, para agregar texto utilizas la función de jquery `text()` mientras que para agregar html hay varias como `append()` `prepend()` `html()` etc.

Comment: Bueno, si tienes una función que se encarga de validar si se cumple o no la condición, para remover el icono solo tienes que ejecutar la siguiente línea: elemento.classList.remove('glyphicon','glyphicon-ok');

Comment: @LPZadkiel si lo de las funciones lo entendi y lo de esta parte " eliminar la clase anterior y escribir la nueva" con esto me has iluminado la mente XD debo cambiar el valor gracias!

Comment: Listo Solucionado muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar un elemento con la funcion `append`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>    </title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#view_compra").append ('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>');
    });

    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <p><b>Compra : </b><span id="view_compra" class="text-success"></span></p>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

En jquery puedes utilizar el método append(), agrega al "parent" la etiqueta que ocupas, e.j:

```
 $("#view_compra").append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>');
```

Si requieres que la etiqueta se agregue al principio de "", se utiliza el método prepend, e.j:

```
$("#view_compra").prepend('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>');
```